Are idempotents in a nonnegatively graded algebra conjugate to homogeneous idempotents?
Let $k$ be a field (assume algebraically closed and $\operatorname{char}(k) = 0$ if it helps) and $R = \bigoplus_{i \geq 0} R_i$ a (unital associative) non-negatively graded $k$-algebra. Furthermore, assume that the grading is locally finite, i.e. $\dim_k(R_i) < \infty$ for all $i$, and that $R$ is generated in degrees $0$ and $1$.
Let $e \in R$ be an idempotent, i.e. $e^2 = e$. Then we can uniquely decompose $e = e_0 + e_+$ where $e_0 \in R_0$ and $e_+ \in \bigoplus_{i \geq 1} R_i$, and it's easy to see that $e_0$ is also idempotent.
Question: Does there exist an automorphism $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(R)$ that takes $e$ to $e_0$? If yes, can we find an automorphism that takes a complete set of primitive orthogonal idempotents to its degree $0$ parts? If no, what additional assumptions are necessary?
I struggle to construct a counterexample (using quivers and relations), but I have not found a proof either. Some partial results:

If $R$ is commutative, then $e_+ = 0$ so the identity works.
If $e_+$ is nilpotent, then $r = (1+e_+(2e_0 -1))$ is invertible and conjugation by $r$ works. This comes from the paper [1].

Point 2 is satisfied e.g. if $R$ is finite dimensional. Similarly, if $R$ is complete with respect to the correct adic topology, we can conclude that $r$ is invertible. But conjugation by $r$ may not be the only option. In [1] there's an example of an ungraded ring and idempotents $e$, $e+b$ such that the corresponding $r$ is not invertible but $e$ and $e+b$ are still conjugate.
Background: I am dealing with two such gradings on the same algebra. For one grading, $R$ is Koszul so $R_0$ is semisimple. As a first step, I would like to be able to fix $R_0$ as a semisimple base to work over. However, choosing homogeneous idempotents for one grading does not yield homogeneous idempotents for the other, so I'm hoping that I can apply an automorphism to fix this problem.
[1] Kanwar, Pramod; Leroy, André; Matczuk, Jerzy, Idempotents in ring extensions., J. Algebra 389, 128-136 (2013). ZBL1295.16025.
